# How to fix this client-server code to print to stdout?

Tags: c, shell, sockets, tcp

I'm trying to write a client-server program in C. For now I have a connection between the server and the client but for some reason nothing happens or prints after the "connected" print.

I've tried sample printing before and after the "connected" but nothing shows on my shell.

my server:

```C
int main(void)
{
    int sockfd, newsockfd, portno, clilen;
    struct sockaddr_in serv_addr, cli_addr;

    sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);//Af_INet is protocol tcp np? ip? - this creates an empty socket
    if (sockfd < 0)
    {
        printf("socket failed\n");
        exit(0);
    }

    if (setsockopt(sockfd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &(int){ 1 }, sizeof(int)) < 0)
    {
        printf("setsockopt failed\n");
        exit(0);
    }

    // calls to bind(), listen() and accept() here
    memset((char *) &serv_addr, 0, sizeof(serv_addr));
    portno = 8888;
    serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET; 
    serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    serv_addr.sin_port = htons(portno);

    if (bind(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0)
    {
        printf("bind failed\n");
        exit(0);  
    }

    listen(sockfd, 5);

    clilen = sizeof(cli_addr);
    newsockfd = accept(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &cli_addr, &clilen);
    if (newsockfd < 0)
    {
        printf("accept failed\n");
        exit(0);
    }
    //end calls

    printf("[Server] Connected\n"); // nothing prints before or after this


      int n;
      char query[BUFFER_SIZE]={0};
      char result[BUFFER_SIZE]={0};
      char *hello = "Hello from client"; 

      send(newsockfd, hello , strlen(hello) , 0 ); //write also doesn't work
      printf("Hello message sent\n"); 
      n = read( newsockfd, query, BUFFER_SIZE); 
      printf("%s\n",query );

       close(newsockfd);
       close(sockfd);
```

my client:

```
int main(void)
{
    int sockfd, portno;
    struct sockaddr_in serv_addr;
    struct hostent *server;

    sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (sockfd < 0)
    {
        printf("socket failed\n");
        exit(0);
    }

    //get host and connect
    portno = 8888;
    server = gethostbyname("localhost");
    if (server == NULL)
    { 
        printf("gethostbyname failed\n");
        exit(0);
    }

    memset((char *)&serv_addr, 0, sizeof(serv_addr));    
    serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    memcpy((void*)&serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr, (void*)server->h_addr, server->h_length);
    serv_addr.sin_port = htons(portno);

    if (connect(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0)
    {
        printf("connect failed\n");
        exit(0);
    }

    //end connect

    printf("client here");//doesn't show on shell screen
    printf("[Client] Connected\n");//shows on shell screen

    int n;
    char *hello = "Hello from client"; 
    char query[BUFFER_SIZE]={0};
    char result[BUFFER_SIZE]={0};
    send(sockfd, hello, strlen(hello), 0);
    printf("Hello message send\n");
    n=read(sockfd,query,BUFFER_SIZE);
    printf("%s\n",query);

        close(sockfd);
```

I compile these with:

gcc -Werror -std=c99 server.c -o server

gcc -Werror -std=c99 client.c -o client

Also, I ran ./server before ./client , the shell screens show "Connected" on both client and server screens and that's it no matter what I write on the screen (either client's or server's)

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: In your server, where does `sock` come from?  It should be `newsockfd`.  It is usual for the server to read what the client writes, must admit I have never tried the other way around.

Comment: Are you on Mingw? You might need to use `recv` instead of `read`, similar to how you had to use `send` instead of `write`.

Comment: @jamieguinan it's Gnu, I'm compiling it in Linux virtual machine. The lecturer said to use read and write, but they also don't work

Comment: DON'T use `SO_REUSEADDR` without knowing the consequences of doing that.

Comment: DON'T use nonportable array literals in parameters of function calls... this is not Java, and it's non-portable.

Comment: Change the hello message in `server.c` to say `"Hello from server"`.  Use `(void*)server->h_addr_list[0]` instead of `(void*)server->h_addr` in the 2nd argument to `memcpy` in `client.c`. It seems to work as expected with those changes. I assume you start the server first and leave it running, then start the client in a separate terminal.

Comment: Also next time it would help to include the `#include` headers in your examples.